# Knightwise “Nearness” By Number Of Moves Required

Tags: graph-theory, chessboard, knight-tours

Given an otherwise empty $n\times n$ chessboard with a knight on one of the squares, define the “knight-closedness” of this board as the maximum possible length of a minimal knight route from one square to another on that board. Determine a closed form for the knight-closedness of such a board in terms of $n$.

I came up with this problem on the train, and I think I’ve determined a few isolated values: for example, I have that the knight-closedness of an $8\times 8$ board is 6. However, I am not learned enough in graph theory to thoroughly resolve this question.

Comment: In other words, "knight-closedness" is the [diameter of the graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory))?

Comment: I suppose if the correct conditions were supplied, then knight-closedness is a diameter- unfortunately, I do not know how to apply that concept to this particular problem.

Comment: I'm just trying to make sure I understand the problem you describe.  There's no magic way to compute the diameter of a graph.  The diameter of a graph is the longest length of a shortest path between two vertices.  Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, for a knight. Learning that there is no closed form is disappointing- oh well, what can I do?

Comment: I think the word "optimal" in the question should be replaced with "minimal". As in "maximum possible length of a minimal knight route from one square to another on that board." The word optimal could mean a lot of things. 

Cool question. +1. I wonder if this has a nice generalization to $m\times n$ boards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any need to be disappointed!

I have not written out a formal proof but, for an $n$ x $n$ board, with $n\ge 6$,the knight-closeness appears to be $n-\lfloor\frac {n}{3}\rfloor$.

The method I applied was to work outwards from a square labelled $0$. All  squares which can be reached directly are labelled $1$. Then all previously unlabelled squares which can be reached from squares labelled $1$ are labelled $2$ and so on.

If you have a go at doing this you will see that what makes the problem solvable is that a clear pattern emerges across the board once one is a few squares away from the start square. For example, as you circle the start square, the squares which have a maximum $x$ or $y$ distance of $5$ from the start square are all labelled $3$ or $4$ alternately.

Comment: What does $int$ mean here? Are you rounding up or down or nearest?

Comment: integer part i.e. rounding down.

Comment: Thanks. I hope you spotted my follow up about a $m\times n$ board above. Could be interesting.

Comment: To the extent that I have carried out the labelling (and assuming I've not made any errors) the pattern looks easier for rectangles when $|m-n|$ is greater than 3 i.e. the slight variations in patterns seem to happen near the diagonal.

Comment: It would be good if someone was interested who could program a computer to carry out the labelling and check that no complications occur for large $m,n$.